# trouble opening .JAR file on Mac

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am having trouble opening a .jar file on Mac. When I double click on the file, it says it can't open and to check the console for possible error messages. I tried running it from the terminal with:

```
> java -jar /Users/BIMMS/Downloads/bimserverjar-1.5.101.jar
```

And I get the following:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.bimserver.starter.Starter.<init>(Starter.java:68)
    at org.bimserver.starter.Starter.main(Starter.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 2 more
MBP-de-Apple:~ BIMMS$ java -jar /Users/BIMMS/Downloads/bimserverjar-1.5.101.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.bimserver.starter.Starter.<init>(Starter.java:68)
    at org.bimserver.starter.Starter.main(Starter.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 2 more
```

I am using a MacBook Pro mid 2012 macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and have this java version

```
> java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

Anyone dealt with this before?
I know the jar is well packed as I downloaded it from:

> https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver/releases
>
> Blockquote

Comment: is a jar created by you? How did you package it?

Comment: Your program may need more jars to be run

Comment: Check the manifest file to see if there is a classpath

Comment: @MauricePerry JAXB is still part of the standard library in Java10. In Java11 it will be removed.

Comment: I did tat @jwenting and I think It doesn't work... the package is ok, I tested it in another machine. thanks in advance

Comment: What about `java --add-modules=java.xml.ws -jar /Users/BIMMS/Downloads/bimserverjar-1.5.101.jar`?

Comment: @user158037 it worked thanks!